# How to find slide show window of Microsoft Power Point

Tags: c++, winapi, powerpoint

I have a simple c++ wIn32 program that allows you to paint over windows in Windows OS.
This program has a UI that lets a user to choose windows he wants to paint over. 
The problem I'm facing is that if a user chooses a specific Microsoft PowerPoint window and than starts a slide show (by pressing 'F5' for example) than another new window is opened on full sceen and my program is unaware of it and does not paint over it.
I need to find out how may I identify this new window, assuming I can perform periodic polling on existing windows using EnumWindows method.
I have tryied using the methods GetAncestor & GetParent on the Slide Show window and on the PowerPoint window to see if they match but both of them return different HWND handle.
Moreover, a solution of identifying that a specific HWND handle is a PowerPoint Slide show window is not sufficient since if I have for example 2 instances of 2 different Power Point windows and the user has chosen to paint only over one of them, than I want to make sure that only if the chosen PowerPoint window is going to slide show window than I will paint over it. If the slide show window was started from the non-chosen PowerPoint window than I don't want to paint over it.

Comment: Remember the `HWND` the user selected and call [WindowFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558.aspx) when they start painting to verify, that the expected window is under the cursor.

Comment: You have missunderstood the issue I am trying to tackle with. The user is not drawing on the window on his own but rather the application. The user is only choosing, once, in advance, what window he wants the application to perform the manipulation on. But to make things more clear and simple the issue I'm tackling with is: assuming I have a HWND handle to a MS PowerPoint window how can I tell if another HWND handle is a "Slide Show Power Point window" (the one that is created when you press on 'F5' key) assosiated with the saved Power Point window handle.